# different content on the website and txt file

Tags: webserver, ssl, text

Good evening, while i'm trying to get SSL from Lets Encrypt i am choosing --manual type to make a file manually(not on the same machine).

So, i am making a file via NANO editor, but when i try to check that everything is okay i get wrong symbols on the screen :D

I thought mb is the problem of encoding? But looks like no, cause when i try do change it to UTF-8 i get the same.

Any ideas?

Thats what `CertBot` needs - "

```
5C-8IBTN-jp-vCxrp4eapHT1NqPUCL5SjqK95X30vto.LDcOeXVIUMwk8RqQR3jg93DXnYmQva61rYnJPGeRh_U
```

"

And what do i get from the url of the file

"`5C-8IBTN-jp-vCxrp4eapHT1NqPUCL5SjqK95X30vto.1e6EJJvuZEPPyEhOLkDeMFxumd461Fa3iAONyy5muHc`"

Also tried to make a file on windows and the to bring it via FTP, but still same.

On the VPS is: `ubuntu 16.04`

Interesting, but when i change 
5C-8IBTN-jp-vCxrp4eapHT1NqPUCL5SjqK95X30vto`.LD...THIS PART..._U`(same row, but a few more symbols) nothing changes on the site.

Comment: Do you verify it using a web browser? Does it match if you verify with curl, e.g. `curl https://url.../path`

Comment: @vidarlo
i used wget to download to another machine and check. And yes, it matches. Problems only with the online version

Comment: Then your problem is clearly caching in the browser.

Comment: @vidarlo, certbot shows me the wrong(the same as in the browser) row. So i think may the problem be caused by the apache2 ?

Comment: So `wget` gives expected result, but  browser and LE gives wrong?

Comment: @vidarlo, yep..

Comment: That's basically impossible. There's something you're missing. Explain in more detail how you verified it using wget, and how you edited it. Are you sure you edit the correct file, for instance?

Comment: I'm using vesta CP with multiple domains linked to one IP. On the initiator of the LE i am copying the file name(just select it(putty client) and paste to another ssh window(nano 'FILENAME')). So, i made a file with the required name. 

Then, i highlight the content, which needs to be pasted into this file(select as well). Then copy it to the destination file(right mouse click). then CTRL + X -> save this name. 
Then i check the encoding type, and tap enter button for verification in certbot.

Comment: How do you verify it with `wget`? Are you able to share the URL? Are you certain the filename and path is correct?

Comment: @vidarlo, http://katrinamebel.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/5C-8IBTN-jp-vCxrp4eapHT1NqPUCL5SjqK95X30vto

check this out :)

Comment: The content of that URL is `5C-8IBTN-jp-vCxrp4eapHT1NqPUCL5SjqK95X30vto.LDcOeXVIUMwk8RqQR3jg93DXnYmQva61rYnJPGeRh_U` which is the same string as you write LE needs in your question... You can verify this with `curl "http://katrinamebel.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/5C-8IBTN-jp-vCxrp4eapHT1NqPUCL5SjqK95X30vto"`